# Is there any way to grab the text and detail text labels of multiple selected table view cells in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have some code right now that gets what cells were selected. The following is my code for doing that:

```
    if let selectedUserRows = self.tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows {

        self.groupUserArray.append(selectedUserRows)
        for index in selectedUserRows {
            let text = groupUserArray[index.row]
            print(text)
        }
    }
```

The new error is saying that the index is out of range!
I was trying to use the logic for grabbing one selected cells text but it does not work. So I was wondering if anyone knew how to grab multiple selected cell's text?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You probably shouldn't need to do this. You are adding the text to the cells via some data source, yes? You should use that data source to get the text you need, not the cells themselves.

Comment: It is not some secondary `groupUserArray` you should be looking in, but your table view's `dataSource` data model, whatever that may be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows` returns a `[IndexPath]?` so if you obtain an array of all the rows and sections of you selected rows. I suppose you are using some sort of collection to populate your tableView (in my example I will call it `textArray: [String]` ) so you can do something like that to get all the text you need:

`if let selectedUserIndexes = self.tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows {
        for index in selectedUserIndexes {
          let text = textArray[index.row]
        }
 }`

Comment: It is giving me an error: fatal error index out of range.

Comment: In my code above you will see groupUserArray. That is the array that gets populated with the selected cells.

Comment: @RohanVasishth you don't have to put the selectedUserRows in an array because you don't have the complete rows but only the indexes of each row. I tried to highlight that by naming it "selectUserIndexes" in my example. Can you please post the code you use to fill the cells?